# How to transpose rows into columns in specific order in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a data (the name of data is testdata) in work-space **60x5 double**. I have 60 different measurement and 5 samples. To calculate in R, I need to save them in an order that my R code can use them. What I need to do is transposing every 5 rows of each column to one row and adding the next transposed rows under those 5 values. You can find an image of what I want to do. As seen in the image, black rectangle should be transposed to column, then red rectangle transpose and added under the columns which is already used for the first step. I need to do this 60 times so at the end it should be **300x1 double**. I hope someone can help me to solve this issue out. Thank you for your time and help.

Best Regards,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this is what you want:

```
A = magic(3); % example matrix
B = A.'; % transpose
B = B(:); % linearize in column-major order
```

This transforms

```
A =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

into

```
B =
     8
     1
     6
     3
     5
     7
     4
     9
     2
```

Comment: Works perfectly @LuisMendo , this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help and time. +1

Answer (score 0):

[Reshape](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) will do exactly what you are looking for:

```
A = magic(5); % Example matrix
B = reshape(A',[],1); % Reshapes the matrix to one vector.
```

Comment: You need to transpose `A` before `reshape` (see my answer)

Comment: Yes, thank you for finding the typo!

Comment: Thank you again, both versions works fine. I didn't understand the difference but gives the same results.